# Filtering in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

I have an Ruby on Rails application in which I have the following resources pets, pet types, vaccinations(the event of vaccinating a pet) and persons. So, pet belongs to a type (a type has many pets) and vaccination belongs to a pet (a pet can have many vaccinations). What I want to do is the following: To have a collapsable list (a select) o all the pet types with a submit button in the vaccinations index, so that I can filter vaccinations by pet types. My code is the following:

This is the index method in the vaccination controler:

```
def index
    if params[:type_id]
      flash[:notice] = "Post successfully created"
      @vaccinations = Vaccination.filter(params[:type_id])
    else
      @vaccinations = Vaccination.all
    end
  end
```

This is the search form in the vaccinations index:

```
<form action="/vaccinations" method="GET">

<%= @type_id %>
        <select name="type_id">  
          <option disabled selected value> Select a classification </option> 
          <% Type.all.each_with_index do | t, index | %>
            <option value="<%= t.id %>" <% t.id.to_s == @type_id ? "selected" : "" %>> <%= t.name%> </option>
          <% end -%>
        </select>
        
  <input type="submit", value="SUBMIT" />
        
</form>
```

And this is my filter method in the vaccination model, the one that I call in the controller.

```
def self.filter(type_id)

        t = Array.new

        for v in Vaccination.all
            if type_id == v.pet.type.id
                t.push(v)
            end
        end

        t

    end
```

What happens is that when I don´t select any pet type, I can see every vaccination as it should be. But when I select any pet type, no matter the type of the pets that have been through a vaccination, it doesn´t show me anything. If i have made three vaccinations to cats an select cat, and filter, it shows me nothing as if I didn´t have any vaccinations. That´s my problem. Sorry for my english, it´s not my first language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of doing it is through relationships.

Example ( should work fine, didn't test it ):

```
  def self.filter(type_id)
    Vaccination.joins(pet: :pet_type).where(
      pet_types: {
        id: type_id
      }
    )
  end
```

Now you will get a list of vaccinations of all the pets with the sent type.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for weeks. Thak you a lot! It works perfectly

Comment: @MatíasBaezaGraf glad it helped :-)